# Что за div-ные отступы?

Tags: html, css

В блоке div содержится элемент img. Высота img 800, а в браузере div в высоту почему-то 804. Паддингов и марджинов нет (как и прочего содержимого, которое может появиться в перспективе).

Comment: Нужно играть в гадалку? Выложите код

Comment: Давыкладывать нечего особо: `<div class="block head">
  <img src="pics/1-head.png" alt="">
 </div>`

Comment: Это естественное поведение блоков к которым применили `inline-block`

Comment: Да я так и понял, что это что-то на уровне генетики ) И вот успел вычитать, что как раз через инлайн-блок это естественное поведение лечить нужно. Не получилось, к слову.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Это проблема многих контейнеров: `block`, `inline`, `inline-block`

```css
.ib {
  display:inline-block;
  border:10px solid red;
}
```

```html
<div class="ib">
<img src="https://i2.wp.com/beebom.com/wp-content/uploads/2016/01/Reverse-Image-Search-Engines-Apps-And-Its-Uses-2016.jpg?resize=640%2C426" width="100"/>
</div>
```

Решается предельно просто указывая `font-size:0;` но если вам понадобится добавить текст создайте для него отдельный блок.

```css
* {
  margin:0;
}
.ib {
  font-size:0;
  display:inline-block;
  border:10px solid red;
}
```

```html
<div class="ib">

<img src="https://i2.wp.com/beebom.com/wp-content/uploads/2016/01/Reverse-Image-Search-Engines-Apps-And-Its-Uses-2016.jpg?resize=640%2C426" width="100" />

</div>
```